# Logistic Regression Import error

Tags: machine-learning

Hi Im using SKlearn for a school project. I cannot importy Logistics regression without getting a numpy float error.

Have not been able to find any solutions online. [image]

Comment: Hi James, Welcome to the community. Please consider upvoting/ marking the answer as correct if you find anything useful on your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following options-

1. Upgrade your numpy package - `pip install numpy --upgrade`
2. Before `from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression`; write these code of lines and run

`np.float = float`
`np.int = int`
`np.object = object`  
`np.bool = bool`